# How can I open a form by click on a link in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm a beginner in React. I want to show a form by clicking on an `<a></a>` tag, please help me. I searched a lot but didn't figure out how to do it.

```
<a href="#adduser" onClick={viewData}>
   Add new user
</a>
```

by clicking on "Add new user" a form will be opened. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp

Answer (score 2):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export function FormBlock() {
  const [showForm, setFormStatus] = useState(false);

  const viewData = () => setFormStatus(true);

  return (
    <div>
      <a href="#adduser" onClick={viewData}>Add new user</a>
      {showForm && (
        <form>
          <input />
          <button type="submit">submit</button>
        </form>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```